# Communicate progress from local Service

Tags: android

An application I'm building uses a local `Service` for downloading files from the web to the phone's SD card. In this app users can browse lists of books, and read them while online. A user can also download a `pdf` copy of a book for offline viewing.

To handle downloads I'm using a locally bound `Service`. I do not want this `Service` to run all the time, only when downloading files. So that the `Service` can shut itself down when its tasks are complete, I am not binding to the service, rather I'm sending an "enqueue for download" command through the `Intent` passed to `Context.startService`.

Books available for download are shown in a list. A user can choose to download a book by clicking on its row in the list. On download, I need to show download progress using a `ProgressBar` on the actual book list row. I need to also show, on the rows, if a book is enqueued for download, or if its download has completed or failed. The books can be shown in different activities throughout the application--in search, or in the user's list of favorite books, for example. When the books are shown in different places, these are not the same objects, but they are uniquely identified by their `bookId`.

Because I do not want to bind to the service from every `Activity`, my tentative plan was to use a `public static final HashMap` on the `Service` class itself to contain a mapping of `bookId` to download status, an `enum` of enqueued, downloading, cancelled, etc. Each book view, when displayed, would check this static HashMap, and if the bookId is in the map, retrieve and display its status. I don't particularly like this idea, but at the moment it's the only way I can think of to retrieve status from the Service without having to bind to it and start it.

Additionally I need to retrieve download progress percent from the `Service`, for a given `bookId`, if it is the active download. Again I'd rather not bind to the service from every activity, so I'm not sure how to go about retrieving current progress from the `Service`. My current plan is to use some sort of singleton mediator, that the `Service` will push updates to, and the views can read from. But I'm not terribly happy with this idea.

The reason I'd like to avoid binding to the `Service` from each Activity is 1.) I'm already running another `Service` and 2.) binding is verbose and I'd like to avoid needing to pass around a reference to the `Service` (but admittedly this isn't too much of a problem).

Perhaps binding to the local `Service` isn't expensive enough to warrant this other setup? Should I not be concerned about binding to it from each `Activity`? Maybe this is a non-issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The reason I'd like to avoid binding
>   to the Service from each Activity is
>   1.) I'm already running another Service

Then consider combining the two.

> 2.) binding is verbose and I'd like to avoid needing to pass around a
>   reference to the Service

Each activity should have its own connection to the service.

> Perhaps binding to the local Service
>   isn't expensive enough to warrant this
>   other setup?

The act of binding to a local service is dirt cheap.

Comment: I'm considering combining the two services, but one is a foreground service and this one does not need to be. As for passing around a connection, I meant within the Activity, to its views and click listeners.

Comment: "I'm considering combining the two services, but one is a foreground service and this one does not need to be." Ah, good logic, there. "As for passing around a connection, I meant within the Activity, to its views and click listeners." OK. I usually have listeners and such be private inner classes of the activity, so there is nothing needed to "pass around".